# How to set "Folders" properties in Sharepoint View

Tags: sharepoint, view

I want to programmatically set the Folders property for a document library to show this view in the folder of a certain content type. I have check the SPView class. But still have no idea how to do that. anyone has any idea?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found this (i know its a bit late) but just in case others want this:

http://manish-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2008_07_01_archive.html

```
list.Views[viewName].Scope = SPViewScope.Recursive;
list.Update();
```